# How much disk space will Gentoo Prefix take up?

Tags: system-installation, disk-usage, gentoo

I'm considering using [Gentoo Prefix](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix/Bootstrap), as a non-root user on some system. However, it's not clear to me how much space it might take - which could be a prohibitive factor for me. So, how much is it? Tens of Megabytes? Hundreds? Gigabytes?

Note:

- I'm bootstrapping it with no special options.
- I'm on an AMD64 machine
- I realize more space will be used later if I install more packages.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the bootstrap script mentions it's working on the latest snapshot of the base system--and it points to the installer script--you can check the size of a snapshot via the [gentoo download page](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/).  You can also check the decompressed size of the archive after downloading by using `gzip`, for example.

As it stands right now, the compressed archive of the stage3 snapshot is 219 Megabytes in size.  Once it decompressed, the files take up 1.3 Gigabytes.  Therefore, I would plan accordingly, and provision about 2 Gigabytes in space, at least.

Comment: 1. I'd like to check before moving forward with this. 2. On SE network sites, the custom is to provide answers outright rather than links to other places where they might be found.